# clock_gettime Speed Difference Across Machines

Tags: time, clock, latency, gettime

I'm trying to use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp)` for timestamping, and I'm finding that it has very different performance across various machines. For example, on a machine with a Xeon X5670 processor running kernel 2.6.27, it takes 682ns per call, while on another machine with the same processor, running kernel 2.6.18, it takes 249ns per call. On a third machine with an X5472 processor running 2.6.27, it takes 183ns per call.

What might account for these differences? Are there kernel options or other settings I can use to improve the latency of these calls?

Thanks.

Elliot